# Data Aggregation in Django Model

Tags: python, django

This is the model concerned:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    guest = models.ForeignKey('hotel.Guest', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    item = models.ForeignKey('hotel.Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paid_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My current view returns a list for a specific guest of all unpaid orders:

```
open_orders = Order.objects.filter(guest = guest, is_paid=False).
```

I would now like to aggregate amount and price per item and date for this list in a new list...

The documentation clearly explains how to do aggregations across an entire QuerySet, and annotations across a relationship but I seem to be stuck with this...

I used `.values('item_id','date').annotate(Sum('amount')).annotate(Sum('price'))`
but that doesn't seem to get it right.

Data Example:

```
open_orders = 
(date=11/11/2011,guest=John,amount=2,item=Beer,price = 30 = order.amount * order.item.price, is_paid = False, paid_date is Null),
(11/11/2011,John,4,Beer,60,False,Null),
(11/11/2011,John,2,Wine,50,False,Null), 
(11/12/2011,John,2,Beer,30,False,Null), 
(11/12/2011,John,1,Wine,25,False,Null), 
(11/12/2011,John,8,Wine,200,False,Null)
```

the desired output would be

```
(11/11/2011,John,6,Beer,90,False,Null),
(11/11/2011,John,2,Wine,50,False,Null), 
(11/12/2011,John,2,Beer,30,False,Null), 
(11/12/2011,John,9,Wine,225,False,Null)
```

Comment: provide data example please

Comment: Try this `.annotate(total_cost=Sum(F('amount')*F('price')))`. I can not check it now, but it looks like what you need.

Comment: What this seems to do is calculate some total price, but I loose the other information like Date and Item.